# add random number to multi fillenames

Tags: python-3.x, random, file-rename

i have a folder: "songs"
inside i have filles "song1singer1.txt", "song2singer2.txt"...
-i want put a random number with 3 digits before fillename like: 
"145_song1singer1.txt","008_song2singer2.txt","049_song3singer3.txt"...
and the next time i can use the same or other program and change the random number with another random number like:
"872_song1singer1.txt","263_song2singer2.txt","492_song3singer3.txt"

thank you for your attention!

i am new in programming and start from Python3 (i use linux)

```
import os

def renamer(folder):
    dirname = folder
    files = os.listdir(folder)
    os.chdir(folder)
    for i in files:
        os.rename(i, dirname + '_' + i)

#import random
#print(random.randint(0,9))

renamer('testrename')
```

Comment: What is the question here? Is there an issue? Please describe what is the problem you face.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
import os
import random

def renamer(folder):
    files = os.listdir(folder)
    for i in files:
        os.rename(os.path.join(folder, i), os.path.join(folder, "{}_{}".format(random.randint(100,999), i)))

renamer('testrename')
```

- `random.randint(100,999)` to genetate random 3 digit number

Comment: ooo!!! Thank you very much!!!!
can you help me with second part of my question?
i want a code for:
remove the random number with 3 digits and add a new one ..(... and the next time i can use the same or other program and change the random number with another random number like: "872_song1singer1.txt","263_song2singer2.txt","492_song3singer3.txt")
thank you again !!!